# XSL For Each Conditional

Tags: xslt

I need to limit the for each selection based on a variable . The below variable is holding the number of failures if any or success if any .

```
xsl:choose><xsl:when test="$allFailureCount = 0">Success</xsl:when><xsl:when test="$allFailureCount > 0">Failure</xsl:when></xsl:choose>
```

After this line I have the XSL for each statement as below which loops through all the nodes consisting of failures as well as success . The need is to loop through select failure 
nodes in case of failure and all nodes in case of success.The expression to detect nodes with failures and success are as follows:

```
/testResults/*[attribute::s='false'] -Failure
/testResults/*[attribute::s='true'] -Success
```

Then I need to limit the following loop

```
<xsl:for-each select="/testResults/*">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you can do this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="/testResults/*[($allFailureCount = 0) or @s='false']">
...
</xsl:for-each>
```

The XPath expression in the for-each loop will select all nodes in case there are failures and only the nodes with attribute `@s='false'` when there are failures.

You can use the short and more readable form of referencing attributes. For example `@s` is the same as `attribute::s`.

Comment: But it did not generate the HTML after applying the transform.Is something wrong here

Comment: Yes, something is wrong, but we have no way of knowing what. The fault is not in the code that @lliyan supplied.

Comment: I tried and it did... (used this xml: ´<testResults>
    <a s="false" texto="elemento a false" />
    <a s="pepe" texto="elemento b" />
    <a s="aaa" texto="elemento c" />
    <a s="false" texto="elemento d false" />
</testResults>´

Comment: I assume so , then please refer this link @
http://gitorious.ow2.org/ow2-proactive/scheduling_rest/blobs/7a5d82b3a0a64c7414311e8bdff20ea14ac75936/performance/jmeter/config/jmeter-results-detail-report_21.xsl which has the XSL in question .Search for the xsl:for-each . I hope this reveals something